# How to format currency symbol so it always comes first to price

Tags: html, typescript, symbols, number-formatting, currency-formatting

I have following code and it always displays the symbol to right side.
There are many symbol which have formatting from
right-to-left. I have tried different ways but not able to get the currency symbol first and then myPrice.
Currency symbol that behaves right-to-left writing - ރ. , د.ك , د.م. , ﷼ , د.ج.

(Mostly any middle-eastern currency symbols)

I have tried adding `-u-nu-latn` to currency_format, but it works only for some currencies. For example, for `MVR (dv-MV)` it will display `MVR 12`, instead I need ރ. and then price.

[image: code]

Comment: [Please post code as code, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15261914)